# What type of data compression involves truncating the first few bits of a piece of data?

Tags: encoding, transmission, compression

We learned about data compression in my class last week and I'm confused about a certain strategy.

My teacher showed us an example where he truncated 8-bit characters by cutting off the first 5 bits, which were all zeros.

- A is 0000 0100 which is truncated to 100
- B is 0000 0010 which is truncated to 010
- The last one is 0000 0011 which is truncated to 011

What type of data compression is this?

Comment: It's probably called "using only the bits you need"? (Assuming there is only at most 2^3 distinct values)

Comment: How is this question related to C++?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having trouble getting answers to any questions related to data structures. I used to get plenty of responses with language-specific questions when I was studying C++. . .

Anyway, I found the answer on this page:

https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Fixed_Bit_Length_Encoding

It's called fixed bit-length encoding.